# How can I get a list of collections in a database using MongoEngine?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'd like to know what call I can make from a python MongoEngine instance to get a list of collection names from my mongodb database? If I were using pymongo directly I could call `db.list_collection_names()`, but I can't find a similar call from MongoEngine. Specifically I'm using flask-mongoengine if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/)

```
from mongoengine import connect

db_name = 'test'
connection = connect(db_name)
connection.get_database(db_name).list_collection_names()
```

### [Flask-MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
db = MongoEngine(app)
#app.config.from_pyfile('the-config.cfg')
#app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {}
db.get_db().list_collection_names()
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also to note, `get_db()` takes as its first argument `alias`, which you can provide the appropriate database alias if you have multiple database connections. Appreciate the help. :-)

Comment: `list_collection_names()` is not in the documentation but it works .  Can you send a link to the exact place in any documentation where this method is shown?  The MongoEngine docs here using the search bar brings up nothing:  http://docs.mongoengine.org/search.html?q=list&check_keywords=yes&area=default#

Comment: @mLstudent33 Check [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html)

Comment: so it's actually a PyMongo method and not MongoEngine.